# Styling tags excluding tags with a particular style

Tags: html, css, ms-word

I am trying to style some html while excluding certain tags. For example, below I have a html which styles 2 pieces of text with different fonts:

```
<span style="font-family: Tahoma, Arial, sans-serif">Test 1</span>
<span style="font-family: Verdana, Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif">Test 2</span>
<span style="font-family: Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif">Test 3</span>
```

I would like to override the style of the spans which are not Arial font to be Times New Roman and I have tried the following css:

```
span {
   font-family: "Times New Roman" !important;
   font-weight: normal !important;
   font-size: 12pt !important;
   font-size-adjust: none !important;
   font-stretch: normal !important;
   font-variant: normal !important;
   font-style: normal !important;
   background-color: white !important;
}
```

The above also changes the style of the Arial text and I would like to exclude the Arial text being styled.

Note that the css is used to style multiple source html and the source html could have more tags in the style, defining the size of text, weight and so on, so the content of the style tag is not predictable.

How do I tell the css to exclude the tags which are styled as Arial font.

I also open the html in Microsoft Word to print the html, so this needs to work using Word as well.

Answer (score 1):

There is no simple way to do that in general, but if the HTML tags are used very consistently, you could set up a style sheet using rules like

```
*[style="font-family: Tahoma, Arial, sans-serif"],
*[style="font-family: Verdana, Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif"] {
   font-family: Times New Roman;
}
```

But you write that “content of the style tag is not predictable” (apparently referring to `style` *attributes*). If this is really so, the answer is “No.”

I wonder what the idea behind this is. If there ever was any point in using Tahoma or Verdana, why would Times New Roman be a suitable replacement for them, but not for Arial? And what should happen in systems that lack a font named Tahoma? Should they get Arial, or Times New Roman?